# Pandas: Drop rows if records conflict in datetime intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe in which I have three datetime columns. One of them is a log date and the other two (let say start and end) are used to define a datetime interval. What I want to do is to drop records if they are conflicting in datetime interval. I would like to keep the record with newest log time and drop the rest.

For example:

| name | start | end | log time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 2022/08/05 09:00:00 | 2022/08/07 08:00:00 | 2022/08/06 08:00:00 |
| r2 | 2022/08/06 09:00:00 | 2022/08/08 08:00:00 | 2022/08/05 08:00:00 |
| r3 | 2022/08/07 09:00:00 | 2022/08/09 08:00:00 | 2022/08/04 08:00:00 |

In this table r1 and r2 are conflicting in intervals, hence I would like to keep r1 as it has the newest log time between the two.

So I would like to get the following result.

| name | start | end | log time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 2022/08/05 09:00:00 | 2022/08/07 08:00:00 | 2022/08/06 08:00:00 |
| r3 | 2022/08/07 09:00:00 | 2022/08/09 08:00:00 | 2022/08/04 08:00:00 |

Answer (score 1):

Below line will get the index which has starttime is grater than logtime and drop the identified indexes.

```
df.drop(df[ (df['start'] > df['logtime'])].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the logtime here is hypothetical. I cannot use the comparison of start and log as it may not always be the case. It is an arbitrary situation in my case, which applies in this specific example.

Comment: can you give me your exact requirement so that i may be able to help you

Comment: The exact requirement is: if there are two rows that are covering the same interval between their start and end then check for the log times of those records and remove the one with older log time. r1 in example is from 5th of August to 7th of August, r2 is from 6th August to 8th August, they both cover 6th and 7th so this is a conflict. In this case comparing their log times r1 is logged on 6th of August whereas r2 is logged on 5th of August, hence solution is removing r2.

Comment: Please check if this works for you.. df.drop(df[ (df['start'] > df['log']) | (df['end'] < df['log']) ].index, inplace=True)